# How to control the dimensions of table in latex?

Tags: tables

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,pageno]{jpaper}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{5cm}{\textbf{Number of \\ Agents}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\shortstack{Baseline sampling \\ phase time~(sec)}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\shortstack{Data layout \\ reorganization time~(sec)}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\shortstack{Data reshaping \\ time~(sec)}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\shortstack{Mini-batch sampling \\ phase time reduction~(sec)}}}\\
    \cline{2-9}
    & \textbf{PP} & \textbf{CN} & \textbf{PP} & \textbf{CN} & \textbf{PP} & \textbf{CN} & \textbf{PP} & \textbf{CN}\\
    %\hhline{~--}
    \hline
    3 & 652 & 373 & 476 & 314 & 417 & 297 & N/R & N/R \\ \hline
    6 & 2385  & 1456 & 1055 & 847 & 1577 & 896 & N/R & N/R \\ \hline
    12 & 8807  & 5266 & 1994 & 1529 & 5994 & 3486 & 9.3\% & 4.8\% \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{Data_reorg}
  \caption{T-1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

In the above picture, I'm trying to organize sub-columns for each column in a table. But somehow, I can't control the dimension of PP and CN columns. Can someone help me to make sure they are of the same size?

Comment: Do you want all PP and CN the same size, or just those under Baseline the same size as each other, those under Data layout the same size as each other, etc?

Comment: Hello, I want all PP and CN to be the same size.

Comment: Is the `jpaper` document class available online? If so, where?

Comment: Basically, the multicolumns are wider than the two columns overwritten, so the extra space is added to the last (second) column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want all PP and CN [columns] to be the same [width].

To assure that (a) the 8 data columns have equal widths and (b) the entire table fits within the textblock, I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment, with a target width of `\textwidth`, rather than a `tabular` environment. And, do allow automatic line breaking in the header cells.

To reduce the amount of visual clutter in the table, I would (a) stop using vertical rules and (b) not use **bold-facing** in the cells of the header row.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,pageno]{article} % I don't have the 'jpaper' document class files
\usepackage[british]{babel}

% new code:
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % centered version of 'X' col. type
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax}C}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
   \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default is 6pt
   \caption{T-1} \label{Data_reorg}
  
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{9}{C} @{}}
   \toprule
   Number of Agents & 
   \multicolumn{2}{E}{Baseline sampling phase time} & 
   \multicolumn{2}{E}{Data layout reorganization time} &
   \multicolumn{2}{E}{Data reshaping time} &
   \multicolumn{2}{E}{Mini-batch sampling phase time reduction} \\
   \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
   \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} 
   & PP & CN & PP & CN & PP & CN & PP & CN \\
   \midrule
    3& 652 & 373 & 476 & 314 & 417 & 297 & N/R & N/R \\ 
    6&2385 &1456 &1055 & 847 &1577 & 896 & N/R & N/R \\ 
   12&8807 &5266 &1994 &1529 &5994 &3486 & 9.3\% & 4.8\% \\ 
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabularx}
  
   \smallskip
   \footnotesize All times in seconds.
\end{table}

\end{document}
```